# How to rotate xtick label in plot from groupby result?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot, rotation

I have a pandas dataframe like this.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[100, 'aaaa', 'bbb'],
                [50, 'eee', 'fff'],
                [10, 'iii', 'jjj'],
                [5,'aaaa','bbb'],
                [3,'eee','fff']],
               columns=['Value', 'A', 'B'])
```

I need to groupby A column and want to make a plot whose xtick is vertical.
So I did

```
y=df1.groupby("A").size()
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
y.plot()
```

However, this does not work.
Does anyone know how to rotate the xtick?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
y = df1.groupby("A").size()
y.plot()
plt.xticks([0, 1, 2], y.index, rotation=90)
```